# How would I make a "wavy" layers pattern onto a wall?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, geometry

So i need to try to achive this kind of pattern on the wall. Is it even possible to make this pattern without maybe modeling it? I thought about array with curve modifier, but i cant make this kind of smooth transition between layers with random "wavy" effect and this method not that flexible.

If anyone can give me some pointers, that would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Do it with Geometry Nodes!

Full parametric realtime control! Non-destructive! Works with Eevee! Real geometry, suited for Export/Manufacturing!

[image]

Basically, you create a high-resolution line in X direction, then instance this line along the points of another line (along Y) and then use a noise (or whatever) texture to control the Z extrusion of all edges. The second extrude controls the Y-thickness of each wave band.

**Note:** Needs 'Realize Instances' to have different waves. Used 'Join Geometry' to close the open backside of the Y-Extrusion.

Here's the file: [image]

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest you the following setup:

[image]

Instead of working with Boolean (which should make things quite slow), here I create this mesh using curves.

1. First create a grid and capture the edges that run along the X-axis.
2. Then move the points using a texture node and remove the previously selected edges, as well as those points whose Z-position is below 0. This way you will get nice curves.
3. Close these curves with `Set Spline Cyclic` and use `Curve to Mesh` to turn them into single meshes.

...Please excuse the unusual brevity of this answer, I'm short on time right now.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is via shader displacement. I used this setup to achieve the pictured effect:

[image: Disp1]

You will need to use Cycles and use a heavily subdivided plane as well as enabling "Displacement and Bump" in the material settings.

[image: Disp2]

Answer (score 0):

You could create an edge, subdivide, duplicate once and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to duplicate several times:

[image]

Give it a *Displace* modifier with the desired texture and *Direction > Z*:

[image]

Apply the modifier, select all in *Edit* mode and extrude horizontally:

[image]

Then select all and extrude vertically:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Or sculpt a subidivided mesh, enable the *Advanced > Sculpt Plane > Z Plane* otpion so that you only move the vertices on Z:

[image]

Then select an edge ring and *Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*:

[image]

Delete the selection, you should have something like that:

[image]

Extrude horizontally:

[image]

Extrude vertically, flatten the extrusion on Z:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: Another funky (non-modeling) shader-based approach with heavy displacement, but this is rather quick-n-dirty and does not reproduce the exact same result as in the question.

[image]

The trick here is to get a noise texture into the 'bricks' inputs of a *brick texture* (the bricks are stretched to fully cover the plane > 'brick width'). This gives you the flexibility to fine-tune the row spacing, texture shape and much more in real-time.

You could also invert every second row:

[image]

**Note:** The 'wave plane' in this demo has 20 subdivisions to get a reasonably smooth displacement.